# Warning using VLCKit in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, vlc

I want to use VLC into my project for stream live camera

I used `pod 'MobileVLCKit'`

and this is my code

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController,VLCMediaPlayerDelegate{

  var mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      mediaPlayer.delegate = self
      mediaPlayer.drawable = playerView
      let url = NSURL(string: "URL HERE")
      mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(URL: url!)
      mediaPlayer.play()
  }
}
```

I have many warning

```
2016-05-24 20:17:02.378 Gideon[2046:458768] creating player instance using shared library
[0000000148b59058] core generic error: option marq-color does not exist
[0000000148b59058] core generic error: option marq-opacity does not exist
[0000000148b59058] core generic error: option marq-position does not exist
[0000000148b59058] core generic error: option marq-refresh does not exist
[0000000148b59058] core generic error: option marq-size does not exist
[0000000148b59058] core generic error: option marq-timeout does not exist
[0000000148b59058] core generic error: option marq-x does not exist
[0000000148b59058] core generic error: option marq-y does not exist
shader program 1: WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'TexCoord1' not read by fragment shader
WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'TexCoord2' not read by fragment shader
```

rstp url works fine

mp4a working but im getting alert error : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbMGa.png)

mjpg not working at all : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5clk.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "Some url work and some not"? Are you able to give examples of URLs that did work and others that didn't? That could help others answer your question.

Comment: These warnings are not important. It's a bug and ignore them. Test urls should be wrong. Try the urls in the VLC media player too.

Comment: rstp working
/ mp4a working but getting alert error
/ mjpg not working at all

Comment: Your MobileVLCKit compilation appears to be incomplete. Those codecs are definitely supported.

Comment: What is MobileVLCKit compilation ? And how can i complete it ?